# Damping in a fluid

Tags: mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to understand damping in a fluid.Take, for instance, water flowing down a surface. I know a damping term $-\alpha\mathbf{u}$, where $\mathbf{u}$ is the velocity field, is added to the sum of forces in the momentum equation. Can I think of this damping term as being analogous to the damping term of a mass-spring oscillator, i.e., that the faster the water flows down the surface, the greater the friction between the water and the surface is, and that's why the damping term is proportional to the velocity?

Comment: How are you modelling your fluid?

Comment: Say incompressible, low viscosity, near constant density. The only other force involved is the pressure. I am not trying to solve this numerically. Just want to know if the damping term above makes at least a bit of sense in some situation. The momentum equation I am thinking of would be                                         $$\mathbf{u}_t+\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{u}=-\nabla p-\alpha\mathbf{u}$$

Comment: No, I don't think it does make sense. For a start, your equation is not dimensionally consistent. You can think of viscosity as damping, but it depends on the gradient of velocity.

Comment: That's strange. I just found a paper by a well-known researcher where he studied well-posedness of the the inviscid 2d Boussinesq equations with damping. This is the momentum equation they studied:   $$\mathbf{u}_t+\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{u}=-\nabla p+\hat{e}_2\mathbf{\theta}-\alpha\mathbf{u}$$ Dimensionality issues are easy to get around, but damping effects, at least to them, is modeled by $-\alpha\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: People studying well-posedness/existence type things often don't get too hung up on the practicalities/physical interpretation in my experience. What paper are you looking at?

Comment: Could be. They also had a $-\beta\theta$ term as damping term in the temperature (or density) equation. One by Jiahong Wu. Guess it should be called mathematical damping.

Comment: Yeah, you could well be correct, it could have been added simply so that the maths worked out.

Comment: Cooool, thanks!